# How to send data to view from Module.php in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I searched for the same and got some answer about it, but did not help.

Those way I tried are as follows:

**1)**

in onBootstrap($e) function:

```
$e->getViewModel()->setVariable('test_variable', 'Hello World!');
        //or
$e->getViewModel()->test_variable = 'Hello World!';
```

2)
I created a function in Module.php

```
function boforeDispatch(MvcEvent $event) {
    $event->getViewModel()->setVariable('test_variable', 'Hello World!');
    //or
    $event->getViewModel()->test_variable = 'Hello World!';
}
```

and called this function inside the onBootstrap($e) function

```
$application = $e->getApplication();
$eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'boforeDispatch'), 100);
```

when I tried in view

```
echo $test_variable;
```

it gives `undefined variable test_variable in ...` error all the times.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to access it like $this->layout()->test_variable

Comment: yes I'm using it already. what I'm asking is echo $test_variable. Just like what we send it from our controller

Answer (score 0):

Try using render event (`MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER`) instead:

```
public function onBootstrap($event){
    $application = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
    $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, array($this, 'addVariablesToViewModel'), 100);
}

public function addVariablesToViewModel($event)
{
    $viewModel = $this->getEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->setVariables(array(
        'key' => 'value',
    ));
}
```

Your view model is probably not yet available on (pre) dispatch